# Simultaneous equation matrices, how do my answers look here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How many solutions does each system have

- A. Unique solution
- B. No solutions
- C. Infintely many solutions
- D. None of the above.

---

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|r}
1 & 0 &  6\\ 
0 & 1 &  -4\\ 

\end{array}\right)$$

My answer: A - Unique solution

x = 6, y= -4

---

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|r}
1 & 0 &  8\\ 
0 & 1 &  -11\\
0 & 0 & 0

\end{array}\right)$$

My answer: A - Unique solution

x = 8, y= -11
Although, I think I recall hearing that if the bottom row is all zeroes, has infintely many solutions?

---

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|r}
1 & 0 & 14 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 15 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\end{array}\right)$$

My answer: B - No solutions

As the bottom row is invalid.
Or am I allowed to 'overlook that'? And say it has infinitely many solutions?

---

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|r}
0 & 1 & 0 & -4\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 

\end{array}\right)$$

My answer: A - Unique solution
y = -4, z = 2

---

Comment: For the second one, the third row puts no further constraints on $x$ and $y$. So unique solution.  For next to last, can't "overlook." For last, not unique, there are $3$ variables, so infinitely many solutions, $x=$ anything, $y=-4$, $z=2$.  By the way, it's not matrices that have or don't have solutions, it is systems of equations.

Comment: Note that "D" could never be an answer for this type of question.